# MPI: maximum RMA window size?

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I'm using MPI_Win to share a fairly large array (for reading only) with different processes and my code works properly one smaller window sizes but begins to fail (local error but not fatal) when I reach about 4 194 304 bytes per process (8 total).
Increasing it further leads to segfault with stacktrace mentioning:

> mca_btl_vader_rdma_frag_advance

as last.
I've tried passing different fragment sizes by using:

> --mca btl_tcp_frag_size 262144

Unluckily that doesn't help.
I've also searched for information about the maximal size of shared RMA window, but couldn't find anything. I guess it'd be platform specific, but I have no idea how to determine it...

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a 4GiB limit, i.e. the largest number that can be stored in an unsigned 32-bit integer. It's possible that this is a limitation of your MPI implementation, but it could also be the way you are setting up the window. For example, if you pass the window size as an unsigned integer then you can never ask for more than 4GiB (and if you try it will probably wrap round to a smaller number).

Can you post the code that declares the window including all variable definitions?

Comment: @DavidHenty thanks, turned out it was a bug on my side. Regarding your answer: I'm using size_t in most places, although sometimes I mix it with int multiplication. This shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Things related to memory sizes / addresses should be of type MPI_Aint for MPI programs, but I doubt there will be any issue with size_t - both of these should give you something larger than a 32-bit integer.